# Reading binary file from sdcard using Stream classes in android

Tags: java, android, file, filestream

Can anybody have any idea how to read a binary file which resides in `sdcard` using Streams, like `Inputstream`, `CountingInputStream` or `SwappedDataInputStream`?

I am using these three streams to read a file which is currently in the `Resources folder`, but now I want to move that file in `sdcard` but I cannot change these stream because I have done so much work on it and I cannot roll back my work.
I am doing it this way but its giving me `FileNotFoundException`. I need your help please.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets(); 
final File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/map");
boolean success = false;         
if(!folder.exists()){
    success = folder.mkdir(); 
} else {
    Log.i("folder already exists", "folder already exists"); 
}

try {
    iStream = assetManager.open(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().concat("/map/map.amf"));
} catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();        
}       
cis = new CountingInputStream(iStream);
input = new SwappedDataInputStream(cis);
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple method that just copies the content of an input stream to an output stream:

```
    /**
     * Copy the content of the input stream into the output stream, using a
     * temporary byte array buffer whose size is defined by
     * {@link #IO_BUFFER_SIZE}.
     * 
     * @param in
     *            The input stream to copy from.
     * @param out
     *            The output stream to copy to.
     * 
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     *             If any error occurs during the copy.
     */
    public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
                    throws IOException {
            byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                    out.write(b, 0, read);
            }
    }
```

It's taken from an app that I made a while ago: http://code.google.com/p/meneameandroid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/dcg/util/IOUtilities.java

And to make sure the dir exists where you want to write/read your data I used something like this:

```
    /**
     * Prepares the SDCard with all we need
     */
    private void prepareSDCard() {
        // Create app dir in SDCard if possible
        File path = new File("/sdcard/MyAppDirectory/");
        if(! path.isDirectory()) {
            if ( path.mkdirs() )
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Directory created: /sdcard/MyAppDirectory");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.w(TAG,"Failed to create directory: /sdcard/MyAppDirectory");
            }
        }
    }
```

The permission to write/read from the SD card is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

*Edited: Linkes updated*

Comment: This means that the path is not correct or there is no file on the SD-Card where you expect to be one. Did you add the external storage permission? I added a function to prepare the SD card, so that least you know that the directory exists.

Comment: i can create the directory and put the files in it.. but main problem is i cannot be able to read that files though Input Stream.

Comment: Try to create a File object pointing to the file you want to read and then check the canRead() method (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)