# Read From a Binary file With FileInputStream

Tags: java, file, binary

I'm starting to learn Java I/O. I have a binary File with Integer data in it and I'm trying to read from it using `FileInputStream` and showing the content of the file on the console. It seems I'm not making the right approach, keep getting **-1** witch means end of file. Here is my code.

```
File f=new File("sunday.dat");
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

try {
    while (true) {

        number=fis.read();
        System.out.println(number);

    }
} catch (EOFException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

fis.close();
```

Comment: what version java are you using?

Comment: @DasDas Irrelevant. The operation of that code is not version-dependent.

Comment: `while (true) {...}` will try to execute its code block infinitely. If you don't have any stop condition (or break/return/throw statements) then `-1` will be printed all the time after you read file content. You need to rethink your loop. BTW if you want to read data as text use `Reader`. `Streams` are for binary data.

Comment: yes- but depends on he java version- we can tell him whats the best way to read the file

Comment: @DasDas He asked why he keeps getting -1. The answer to that is not version-dependent.

Comment: @Pshemo The question explicitly states the file is binary.

Comment: @EJP Yes, I know, but sometimes OP describes X but wants Y. I wrote last part of my comment based on "File with Integer data" since OP may want to print actual integers, not their binary/byte form (even if it comes from binary file).

Comment: so how must i aproach it if y want to print the integer content? of the binary file?

Comment: im Using java 8,¿witch is the right aproach to read the binary file? and show the content on the console  or is this no possible?@DasDas , @EJP

Comment: @EJP that is my idea apologizes for not expressing myself better!

Comment: duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862581/reading-binary-file-from-sdcard-using-stream-classes-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems I'm not making the right approach, keep getting -1 which means end of file.

Exactly so. It means end of file. You should only get it once. You keep getting because you aren't testing for it and breaking out of the loop when you get it.

Instead you seem to be relying on catching `EOFException,` which is never thrown by that method.

Comment: Which approach do you suggest to solve the problem the best way? change the while loop condition? or would you approach the problem in a different way, thanks a lot!